# Pipe "|" symbol is causing errors in typescript definition file

Tags: typescript

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and latest Typescript compiler 1.6.2, but I still have problems with definition files. And I get error for every method declaration that have pipe symbol for designation various types of argument. See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGZ63.jpg) for jquery text() method parameter types error.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of that definition file? The screenshot is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: I think there's no need to include the definition file. It's huge file and everyone can look at it on DefinitelyTyped github repository.Link is below, and I use the same version of file. Just search for "text(" in page, and you will get to line 2723 where 
'code'text(text: string|number|boolean): JQuery; is defined. [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts)

Comment: In the mean time I've installed Visual Studio 2015, and seems that it's not complaining about that. But I need to keep using VS 2013 for some time. I know this should not be an issue with TS compiler. So I would really like to know why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

> Pipe “|” symbol is causing errors in typescript definition file

This is called a `union` type and is definitely supported in TypeScript 1.6. Check your visual studio tsc version (`tsc -v`).

Comment: Checked. It's 1.6.2 version as said above.